# creating dataframe efficiently without for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with some advertising data, such as email data. I have two data sets:

1. one at the mail level, that for each person, states what days they were mailed, and then what day they were converted.

   ```
   import pandas as pd

   df_emailed=pd.DataFrame()
   df_emailed['person']=['A','A','A','A','B','B','B']
   df_emailed['day']=[2,4,8,9,1,2,5]
   df_emailed
   print(df_emailed)

     person  day
   0      A    2
   1      A    4
   2      A    8
   3      A    9
   4      B    1
   5      B    2
   6      B    5
   ```
2. I have a summary dataframe that says whether someone converted, and which day they converted.

   ```
   df_summary=pd.DataFrame()
   df_summary['person']=['A','B']
   df_summary['days_max']=[10,5]
   df_summary['convert']=[1,0]
   print(df_summary)

     person  days_max  convert
   0      A        10        1
   1      B         5        0
   ```

I would like to combine these into a final dataframe that says, for each person:

- 1 to max date,
- whether they were emailed (0,1) and on the last day in the dataframe,
- whether they converted or not (0,1).

We are assuming they convert on the last day in the dataframe.

I know to do to this using a nested for loop, but I think that is just incredibly inefficient and sort of dumb. Does anyone know an efficient way of getting this done?

Desired result

```
df_final=pd.DataFrame()
df_final['person']=['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B']
df_final['day']=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,1,2,3,4,5]
df_final['emailed']=[0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]
df_final['convert']=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0]
print(df_final)

   person  day  emailed  convert
0       A    1        0        0
1       A    2        1        0
2       A    3        0        0
3       A    4        1        0
4       A    5        0        0
5       A    6        0        0
6       A    7        0        0
7       A    8        1        0
8       A    9        1        0
9       A   10        0        1
10      B    1        1        0
11      B    2        1        0
12      B    3        0        0
13      B    4        0        0
14      B    5        1        0
```

Thank you and happy holidays!

Comment: great catch thank you. made edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A high level approach involves modifying the `df_summary` (alias `df2`) to get our output. We'll need to

- `set_index` operation on the `days_max` column on `df2`. We'll also change the name to `days` (which will help later on)
- `groupby` to group on `person`
- `apply` a `reindex` operation on the index (days, so we get rows for each day leading upto the last day)
- `fillna` to fill NaNs in the `convert` column generated as a result of the reindex
- `assign` to create a dummy column for `emailed` that we'll set later.

Next, index into the result of the previous operation using `df_emailed`. We'll use those values to set the corresponding `emailed` cells to `1`. This is done by MultiIndexing with `loc`.

Finally, use `reset_index` to bring the index out as columns.

```
def f(x):
    return x.reindex(np.arange(1, x.index.max() + 1))

df = df2.set_index('days_max')\
        .rename_axis('day')\
        .groupby('person')['convert']\
        .apply(f)\
        .fillna(0)\
        .astype(int)\
        .to_frame()\
        .assign(emailed=0)

df.loc[df1[['person', 'day']].apply(tuple, 1).values, 'emailed'] = 1
df.reset_index()

   person  day  convert  emailed
0       A    1        0        0
1       A    2        0        1
2       A    3        0        0
3       A    4        0        1
4       A    5        0        0
5       A    6        0        0
6       A    7        0        0
7       A    8        0        1
8       A    9        0        1
9       A   10        1        0
10      B    1        0        1
11      B    2        0        1
12      B    3        0        0
13      B    4        0        0
14      B    5        0        1
```

Where

```
df1 = df_emailed
```

and,

```
df2 = df_summary
```

Comment: I AM NOT WORTHY, I AM NOT WORTHY, I AM NOT WORTHY.

Comment: @TrexionKameha I'll take that as the answer being useful to you. Happy holidays :-)

Comment: Yes you did! Thank you. How would I add another column to the key, for example, campaign? IE for person A, and person B, I had capaigns X, Y, and Z, and I would like convert at each step. Is that simple? I tried myself and ran into an issue with the duplicate key.

Comment: @TrexionKameha okay, that may or may not need a different answer. I'm finding it hard to visualise. Is there any possibility of opening a new question? Would help.

Comment: Sorry please disregard, there were duplicates with my data. I changed all of the indexes and it worked. thank you!